# How do I exit the msql execution process?. Commit doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I get no errors after completing the sql commands but for some reason, i've tried commiting but that doesn't help. I can't get out of the execution process. I'm abit rusty in sql.

eg.

```
INSERT INTO 'login.'Users' (
'> 'id',
'> 'username',
'> 'password',
'> 'user_email'
'> )
'>
'> VALUES ( NULL, 'manager', 'password', 'admin@sss.com' );
'> VALUES ( NULL, 'Bill Hick', '2edW', 'puo@sssc.com' );
'> VALUES ( NULL, 'Jim Burn', 'dsdFfrr', 'jim@sscs.com' );
'> VALUES ( NULL, 'Rob Slater',  'v$5wwc', 'rob@wsd.com' );
'> VALUES ( NULL, 'Sandra Ante', 'Hysdp&', 'sa@asd.com' );
'> VALUES ( NULL 'Peter Piper' 'sdPn&s' 'pp9@sasd.com' );
'>
'>
'>
'>
'>
.
.
.
.
```

And it goes on....

Comment: btw your mistake is `'login.'Users'`  should be `\`login\`.\`Users\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do like this to get out of execution process

```
mysql > '\c
```

**From some book**

> The **mysql>** prompt displayed by mysql is just one of several different
>   prompts that you might see when entering queries. Each type of prompt
>   has a functional significance because mysql varies the prompt to
>   provide information  about the status of the statement you're
>   entering. The following table shows each of these prompts.

```
Prompt            Meaning
mysql>            Ready for new statement
->                Continue entering statement until a terminator like is entered
'>                Waiting for end of single-quoted string (')
">                Waiting for end of double-quoted string or identifier (")
`>                Waiting for end of backtick-quoted identifier (`)
/*>               Waiting for end of C-style comment (*/)
```

> The **mysql>** prompt is the main (or primary) prompt. It signifies that
>   mysql is ready for you to begin entering anew statement.If in fact you
>   have mistyped the current statement by forgetting to close a quote,
>   you can cancel the statement by entering the closing quote followed by
>   the \c clear-statement command.

And change `INSERT INTO` AS

```
INSERT INTO Users(id,username,password,user_email) 
VALUES 
( NULL, 'manager', 'password', 'admin@sss.com' ),
( NULL, 'Bill Hick', '2edW', 'puo@sssc.com' ),
( NULL, 'Jim Burn', 'dsdFfrr', 'jim@sscs.com' ),
( NULL, 'Rob Slater',  'v$5wwc', 'rob@wsd.com' ),
( NULL, 'Sandra Ante', 'Hysdp&', 'sa@asd.com' ),
( NULL, 'Peter Piper', 'sdPn&s', 'pp9@sasd.com' );
```

Comment: It doesn't add the rows into the table.

Comment: Change `INSERT INTO 'login.'Users'` to `INSERT INTO login.Users`

Comment: I then get this. 

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id',
    'username',
    'password',
    'useremail'
    )

Comment: updated my answer with INSERT statement

Comment: Accept the answer if it works for you !